# Windows batch "rmdir /s /q" empty a folder but it is still there (but 0KB) and can't access

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, svn

I use Windows 7 x64. I have a svn checkout Working folder, say "Working".
When I use a batch file or just open CMD, I did

```
del "%currPath%\Working" /s /f /q
rmdir "%currPath%\Working" /s /q
```

The folder "Working" is still there, but the size is 0KB. And when I want to enter into this folder, I got an error message like:

```
Can't access ...\Working.
Permission denied.
```

This is not a general situation for all chekcout folders. Even for this specific folder "Working", sometimes it works.

If I wait for a while, sometimes 10 minutes, the folder will disappear.

I totally have no idea what may cause this issue.

Comment: I've seen behavior similar to this when a program is holding the file/folder open. For example, download a podcast .mp3 file, open it in Windows Media Player, try to delete it. Still there. Close WMP and suddenly it's gone. SVN shell integration would likely hold the folder open, for example.

Comment: wait for it to be 'locked', then run handle.exe from sysinternals.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx  -- then `taskkill /f /im thatapp.exe`